# Replacing null String to empty String

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a small problem, but it's hard for me to solve it.

I have built a String that is a collection of some object's attributes, constructed and delimited by `||`. But whenever I have some `null` attribute, it keeps on printing `null`, I want to replace `null` with empty string.

For example, for the input

```
ADS||abc||null||null
```

I want it to become

```
ADS||abc||||
```

I tried these two, but they didn't work:

```
string.replace(null,"")
string.replace("null","")
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: nope,it should be ||null|| to be ||||

Comment: Did you set the string to the result of `replace()`? E.g. `string = string.replace("null", "")` (You need to do this because Strings are immutable)

Comment: As alluded above, Java `String` objects are **immutable**. You can create a new string based on the existing one but it's impossible to change the existing `String` itself.

Comment: THANKS! I forgot this simple and silly mistake..it's working. Thanks guys.

Comment: What if one of the attributes happens to contain "null"? Example: `AnullDS||nullbc||null||null`. Hopefully I can't create a bank account with the name `Nico Pratamanull` and access your money.

Comment: that's one problem though,then we just need to do some validation if the string is null,replace it with "" instead of replacing "null"..but for now,it works just fine..is there any other easier way?thanks for bringing this up though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Strings are immutable, you should assign your String variable to the result of the `replace` method.

```
String str = "ADS||abc||null||null to become ADS||abc||||";
str = str.replace("null", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
ADS||abc|||| to become ADS||abc||||
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean below code?

```
String[] names = new String("ADS||abc||null||null to become ADS||abc||||").split("\\|\\|");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String name : names) {
    list.add(name.replace("null", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ADS||abc||null||null";
        s = s.replace("null", "");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**Output**

```
ADS||abc||||
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot that string is immutable, add this to your code:

```
String string = string.replace("null","");
```